# Progress bar for jQuery post

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery Ajax to make POST requests. Is there a way to display progress in a progress bar?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412629/jquery-progressbar-and-ajax-requests - here You have the answer

Answer (score 0):

sadly this cant be done , but there is a small trick you can do to accomplish that ..
you can show an increasing progress bar -this is just an image that counts -(say to 90),
and when the query success then make it show the image for the 100% completion ..

so just to wrap it :-
two animating images one counts to 90% fairly fast as those wont take much long and the other just jumps to 100% ... i dont really know if there is some sort of other way , but i believe there isnt